# Making a template function work with both lvalue and rvalues pointer arguments

Tags: c++11, templates

I currently have a memory leak in my project. To resolve the memory leak, I am trying to replace the pointers into `std:: unique_ptr`. The pointer to the heap is not from my project, but rather from a library called Xerces(an XML parsing library). 
In this library, it can transcodes char * to XMLCh * in both ways. 
So in real code, it comes like ..

```
XMLCh * xmlstr = XMLString::transcode("abc",...);
char * charstr = XMLString::transcode(xmlstr,...);
```

since both methods allocates heap area and returns the pointer for it, I should explicitly call

```
XMLString::release(xmlstr);
XMLString::release(charstr);
```

after using it to clean up. I want to write a custom deleter for two types (char * and XMLCh *) using std::unique_ptr.

The release method has a type of

```
XMLString::release(char **str);
XMLString::release(XMLCh **str);
```

It is using double pointer because it sets the pointer to null after release. 
I thought to make the template accept reference pointers like this,

```
template<typename T>
void release(T *& ptr){
    XMLString::release(ptr);
}
```

but just realized that it will be possible to

```
XMLCh * xmlstr = XMLString::transcode("abc",...);
auto uptr = unique_ptr<XMLCH, decltype(&release<T>)>(xmlstr)
```

do this, but not possible to

```
auto  xmluptr = unique_ptr<XMLCH, decltype(&release<T>)>(XMLString::transcode("abc",...));
```

do something like this, because it is accepting a rvalue in the parameter but the argument is a reference pointer. Is it possible to instantiate both cases writing only one template function? 
By the way, I am using c++11.

Comment: You create a `std::unique_ptr` object, and try to initialize a `XMLCh*` variable with that. That will of course not work. Other than that it looks fine.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude , sorry, I made a type-o in the code. I edited the last part. The problem is that it is accepting reference as an argument, but the returned pointer from XMLString::transcode is actually a r-value pointer.

Comment: And what I meant by 'working' is to assign the pointer to null after the release, which is intened by XMLString::release();

Comment: What is the prototype of `XMLString::transcode`? Does it return a plain pointer? Then it can be used directly in the construction of the `unique_ptr`. There's really not such thing as an "r-value pointer". If the function returns a pointer, it returns pointer, plain and simple. If you try it, what problems do you get? What errors do you get? Are you perhaps returning a pointer to a local variable?

Comment: Also, if you use `unique_ptr` there's really no reason to "assign the pointer to null after the release".

Comment: By the way, how do you think e.g. `std::unique_ptr<SomeType>(new SomeType)` would work if it didn't allow "r-value pointers"? It's really no different than calling a function which returns a pointer. You really need to elaborate on the *actual* problems you're having (not on the wanted solution), first by [reading about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then by learning how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can show us.

Comment: Maybe I had been overcautious about the possibility of a dangling pointer. The fact that the allocation was not coming from my code may have drove me. You're totally right about making a good question.

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand correctly, your problem is that `XMLString::release` takes a pointer-to-point and it does not fit into the `unique_ptr` release function. Well, the correct solution is to wrap it like

```
template<typename T>
void release(T *ptr){
    XMLString::release(&ptr);
}
```

The `XMLString::release` will only null-out the copy of the pointer inside the wrapper, but since the `unique_ptr` takes care of rendering itself unusable itself, you don't need that functionality of `XMLString::release`.

In either case, the type of the `release` wrapper does **not** affect how the `unique_ptr` is constructed, because the `release` wrapper will be called with the internal member of the `unique_ptr` as argument. So either `unique_ptr` accepts that argument, and both assignments will work, or `unique_ptr` won't accept it and neither will.

That said, the point of unique_ptr is that you wrap the pointer in it immediately when you get it. So don't store it in variable before.